# ios open call history

Tags: ios, call, history

How to open the call history programmatically?

[image]

Sort of:

```
call://history
```

?

Comment: You can't there is no custom url for doing this and no available API for doing this ever.

Comment: This is not possible in genuine iPhone device.

Comment: Probably not a good idea posting real phone numbers around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CANNOT** do this because there is no available API for doing so and no custom URL ever for opening it directly into that app.

So it is **NOT** possible sorry.

I'd also say if you even found a way to do this it would be rejected under:

> **2.5** Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

because you'd have to use a non-public API to do this.