# Fetch recent phone calls log

Tags: ios

I want to fetch recent call logs. Recent call logs like dial number, receive call, missed call, etc.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002583/ios-open-call-history, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693702/access-call-history-on-ios, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656419/how-to-get-call-history-in-iphone, and some more ... just search for `[ios] call history`.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do the same in ios

It is strictly prohibited.

You can do it with jailbroken devices